# Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'path'" in

Tags: python-2.7, attributeerror, try-except

I am debugging python code (python2.7.12) as my code works but I get NULL for all variables when streaming tweets into the database.

The error I got is:

```
Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'path'" in <function _remove at 0x10068f140> ignored
```

I am assuming this error is from the code below:

```
def put_tweets_in_database(tweets):
    print "putting tweets in database"
    errors = 0
    count = 0

    for tweet in tweets:
        try:
            commit_tweet_to_database(tweet, count, len(tweets))
            count += 1  
        except Exception as e:
            print e
            session.rollback()
            errors += 1
    print 'there were {} errors'.format(errors)
```

I don't think the function `commit_tweet_to_database()` is wrong...

Do you have any idea...? I would appreciate any help!

Thank you.

Comment: I'm betting there's no user-defined `_remove` in context, there was no line number for the error and the exception is raised between loop iterations. So I suspect it has something to do with the loop iterator, possibly a bug in Python.

Comment: Note: The error is only occurring for me when stepping through the code with `pdb` (no rhyme intended).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'path'" in <function _remove at 0x10068f140> ignored
```

This tells that in function `_remove` an attribute `path` was tried to be accessed on a `NoneType` object. `NoneType` objects have no attributes. So may be you need to look at `_remove` function and start debugging from there.

Answer (score 2):

I am also dealing with this error. I tried using the browser.close() method, and while it does stop the - 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'path' - from being displayed, I am left with a bunch of open firefox browser instances.

The .close() method closes chrome, and it doesn't throw the NoneType error in firefox, but it leaves firefox open. The .quit() method closes both browsers, but it throws the error for firefox.

I am using django's StaticLiveServerTestCase class for my code.

I wrote a little debugger loop to test things out. Just uncomment and comment out the .quit() and .close() statements.

```
class BaseTestCase(StaticLiveServerTestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUp(self):

        self.firefox = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.chrome = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.browsers = [self.firefox, self.chrome]

    @classmethod
    def tearDown(self):

        for browser in self.browsers:
            if browser == self.firefox:
                print('firefox')
                browser.close()
                # browser.quit()
            elif browser == self.chrome:
                print('chrome')
                browser.close()
                # browser.quit()
```

I still don't know the answer, but I think this is a step in the right direction.

Comment: Now I'm wondering whether the original question is actually being answered by @Dung and myself.

Comment: This isn't really the answer to the original question ... though it is an exception from the Python Selenium 3.x module, from selenium.browser.quit().

Comment: close() is different that quit()... you can't just interchange them

Comment: Corey, could you expand on that? I'm a bit hazy on the issue myself.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing this line of code:

```
import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
```

Guess the script already called `pdb.set_trace()` and you are trying to override it. This might be a reason for the issue.

Comment: pudb was causing this for me.  When I removed ```import pudb; pu.db``` the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as-though your "try" clause is failing, causing the exception to be printed? I'd likely add more debugging to the Exception catch, such as printing out the arguments to commit_tweet_to_database, just to make sure you're passing viable parameters.

Answer (score -4):

I have the same error and here is my case:

browser = webdriver.Firefox()

browser.get('http://www.google.com')

print browser.title

- this following will give me error message: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'path'

browser.quit()

- this following will not give error

browser.close()

## So the issue is that you have use the wrong method for your object!

Comment: close() is different that quit()... you can't just interchange them