# How to avoid getting `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'path'` on selenium quit()?

Tags: python, selenium, exception, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

When running *Selenium Webdriver Python script,* one gets a `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'path'` after executing `self.driver.quit().` 
Enclosing `self.driver.quit()` in `try/except` does not help, namely:

```
$ cat demo_NoneType_attribute_error.py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver
import unittest

class TestPass(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def test_pass(self):
        pass

    def tearDown(self):
        print("doing: self.driver.quit()")
        try:
            self.driver.quit()
        except AttributeError:
            pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()

$ python demo_NoneType_attribute_error.py
doing: self.driver.quit()
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'path'
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 19.807s

OK

$
```

### Does anyone have an idea how to avoid the `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'path'` message?

Note:
Since this issue was already reported by the beginning of November (see URLs below), it should have had a patch by now - but upgrading `selenium` to latest from `pip` did not eliminate it.

- [Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'path'" in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38574821/exception-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-path-in)
- [Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'path'" in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38574821/exception-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-path-in)

Environment: Selenium 3.0.2; Python 2.7; Cygwin 32 bits on Windows 7.

Comment: this was fixed in selenium 3.0.2.  you *must* be on an older version. https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/9157c7071f9900c2608f5ca40ae4f518ed373b96

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems a bug in `selenium 3.0` version

Update the `quit()` method definition in `webdriver.py` of `firefox`  as follows (relative path: `..\Python27\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py`):

change the following line in `quit()` method:

```
shutil.rmtree(self.profile.path) #which gives Nonetype has no attribute path
if self.profile.tempfolder is not None:
    shutil.rmtree(self.profile.tempfolder)
```

to

```
if self.profile is not None:
    shutil.rmtree(self.profile.path) # if self.profile is not None, then only rmtree method is called for path.
    if self.profile.tempfolder is not None:
        shutil.rmtree(self.profile.tempfolder) # if tempfolder is not None, then only rmtree is called for tempfolder.
```

**Note**: wherever `self.profile` is used, do the same. i.e., move the code to if condition as mentioned above.

---

In `Selenium 3.0`, `profile` and `binary` moved to `firefox_options` instead of their separate existence as `firefox_profile` and `firefox_binary` respectively in `Selenium 2.0`.

you can verify this in `webdriver.py` (of `firefox`) in `__init__` method.

relevant code in `__init__` method:

```
if firefox_options is None:
    firefox_options = Options()
    print dir(firefox_options) # you can refer binary and profile as part of firefox_options object.
```

Note: Observed that `firefox_options.profile` still giving `None`, which might be an issue to be fixed in `selenium 3.0`

Comment: Thanks @Naveen, worked as advertised: if you have the time (and inclination), why not write a patch - implementing your suggestion - and get gloria mundi?

Comment: @boardrider, glad it worked for you. I need to know the selenium webdriver in its totality in order to make changes (or fix things). the answer is just my perspective and I don't know the real reason behind those changes, so can't comment on that.

Comment: Let's hope the Selenium guys monitor SO, so they'd get a nudge to create a patch themselves...

Comment: @boardrider you could at least file an issue with the Selenium team referring to this thread.

Comment: wasn't this already fixed with https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/9157c7071f9900c2608f5ca40ae4f518ed373b96 ?

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg, just checked. It is fixed. updated selenium using `pip install -U selenium`, which upgraded selenium from `3.0.1` to `3.0.2`, which has `if condition` to check `profile` is not None.

Comment: @boardrider, try by upgrading selenium version using `pip install -U selenium` and confirm as you are already using `3.0.2` version.

Comment: `pip list | grep -i selen` gives: *selenium (3.0.2)*

Comment: @boardrider, try as suggested in the issue logged by you here https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3239. suggest running the command `pip install -U selenium` again (I knew you are already using `3.0.2` version but that may not be the latest).

Comment: I implement your answer's suggestions @Naveen, and my code works okay now. So, since I'm already at `3.0.2` I prefer not to `pip`(as that would/may overwrite your changes ("if it ain't broken" and all that).